# What is the best way to select a few entries in a metas table?

Tags: php, mysql

FYI, I'm using php and **MySQL**.

I was wondering what is the best way to select a few (and determined) entries in a "metas" table to link them to the principal element.

For more explanations, I have a table "users" which contains principal informations : id, email, nickname.
I also have an other table, "users_metas" which contains a lot of differents informations with one entry for an information (i.e. entry1 : avatar for user1, entry2 : connection for user2, ...).

For now, when I need some specifics informations from the metas table, I'm doing it like this :

```
SELECT u.u_nickname, u.u_email, um1.um_value as u_avatar, um2.um_value as u_connection
FROM users as u
 LEFT JOIN users_metas as um1 ON um1.um_uid = u.u_id AND um1.um_name = "avatar"
 LEFT JOIN users_metas as um2 ON um2.um_uid = u.u_id AND um2.um_name = "connection_date"
WHERE u.u_id = :u_id
```

It works, and after a few "benchmarks" it's way faster than doing other `SELECT` queries like :

```
SELECT u.u_nickname, u.u_email,
  (SELECT um_value FROM users_metas WHERE um_uid = u.u_id AND um_name = "avatar") as u_avatar,
  (SELECT um_value FROM users_metas WHERE um_uid = u.u_id AND um_name = "connection_date") as u_connection
...
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way to do that. Of course, there is not just `avatar` and `connection` informations in the metas table, but a lot of others.

Thanks for you advices.

*I'm using "metas" term to speak about diverse informations about an element*

Comment: This is an EAV data model. It has advantages, but also disadvantages to e.g. a row with one column per attribute ("metas"), which would only require one join, but needs more space if you don't use all attributes, and gets complicated when attributes differ from user to user. Having said that - assuming you have correct indexes (a two-column index `um_uid` and `um_name`) columns, your query is fine.

Comment: Thx @Solarflare ! I now have the name of this data model, haha.
The last few minutes, I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to use just one `LEFT JOIN` and put the name of the metas I want in the `ON` condition, then treat the _datas_ I got with php.... ? You know what I mean ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. It depends on how you need your data (rows or columns) and if you e.g. want to join another table depending on values you got here. This is actually the use case when you don't know which attributes a specific user has (because they might differ from user to user): you just grab all and evaluate them. It can be faster depending e.g. on how many attributes you want to grab and how many are in the database (and it's less to write), but assuming the correct index, it's not that much faster (and you have to go through the resultset in php to look for a specific attibute).

Comment: Allright ! Thank you very much for your informations ! It helps a lot :)

Comment: @Solarflare I have an other question... What if we simply collect all the meta-datas of a user (or w/e element) in a serialize data in a longtext column in the data base ? If so, we simply have one entry (ie line) for each element, but a (very) big column "metas" which could contains two informations or a hundred ?
There's just one column to get in the SQL-query, unserialize it and get the value from the key we're looking for. Is it a good way ?

Comment: Well, that also depend on what you are doing. If you just want to store the data and use/change it only in your app, you can do that (but you don't need a database for that). Serialized data becomes (not completely, but mostly) unusable inside the database, it will basically just store the data. How many users are we talking about that you are trying to optimize that much? You can have hundreds of millions of rows and MySQL can still get the data in 0.1s if properly indexed. Maybe post your explain output (write `explain ` directly infront of your query), so we can have a look at your indexes.

Comment: @Solarflare Actually since I asked the new question, I read some stuff on the subject. Truth is : it's not a good idea for my use ! Thx for all your informations, I have now all the things I need :).

Comment: @Solarflare Hi again, I'm just thinking about what you said a week ago : "assuming you have correct indexes columns, your query is fine". Does this mean I should put a "Index" status to those columns ? It does change anything except for the query speed ? Thx :)

Comment: Yes, pure indexes will only impact speed (to be precice: not only faster, but usually faster). But there are things that might be called indexes, e.g. `unique indexes`, that do more than just change speed, so be sure to click the right buttons wherever you click your buttons. The index you need here is, as written, a composite index over `um_uid` AND `um_name`, so a two-column index in that order (well, actually it should be the `unique index` I mentioned, which does more than change speed, it ensures that every combination of (`um_uid`, `um_name`) only exists once, which is what you want).

Comment: @Solarflare Oh god. I have to learn those indexes things. Thx for the advice, i'll take a look :o